# mock takeEvery in redux testing

Tags: redux, redux-saga, react-typescript, redux-saga-test-plan

```js
export function* saga() {
  yield* takeEvery(somethingActions.doSomethingElse, pollSaga);
}
```

I'm trying to write a test for `somethingActions.doSomethingElse`, which is fine and all, but I have this line that kicks off `pollSaga`. I would like to mock the entire call out to `pollSaga`, i.e. disable it and test it later. Is there a way to do this?

I am just calling `dispatch` on the `somethingActions.doSomethingElse`, which works (and the test passes), but `pollSaga` is being called as a result of the `takeEvery` and the error output is just annoying. I could use `redux-saga-test-plan` if that makes it easier.

I have tried

```js
return expectSaga(saga)
      .withState(...)
      .provide([
        [matchers.take(somethingActions.doSomethingElse), undefined],
      ])
      .dispatch(somethingActions.doSomethingElse(...))
      .run();
```

but this does not seem to work; the `pollSaga` is still being called.

Thank you!